# how to reupload app after deleting app from appstore

Tags: app-store

I got a strange isssue regarding appstore, recently we upload .ipa with 1.5 version to appstore , which is approved and ready for sale state. Right now we got an issue so we want temporarily remove the app from appstore, for that I can follow these steps **Go** in Manage your `Applications > [Your Application Name] > Rights` and Pricing Click on `"Deselect All`" App Stores and "Save". The Application will change state to "Developer Removed". so my question was , if I want to reupload my app what about the version for my app, can I continue from my current version or I need to start from 1.0?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can upload a new binary, and set the availability of that binary (the selected stores) back to whatever locales you want to sell in.

There's no need to start again from 1.0; you can follow whatever numbering scheme you want.

(Note that you should make sure to pick a number bigger than 1.5, though, so that the update is available to people using the current version of your app.)